# Wordpress Speed

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for some additional ideas on how to speed up our WordPress Portal, which we've built from the ground up.

The pages are taking a little longer that would like to load and it causing some concerns.

Things i've tried:

Putting CDN's in for as much as possible.

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-stylesheet', 
'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font- 
 awesome.min.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
```

- Optimising images.
- Keeping all plugins updating and removing
- unnecessary ones. Reducing database calls
- Reducing Post revisions
- Hosting is on it's on VPS. The portal is the only thing on the VPS and the VPS is of good specification
- A variety of code changes to speed up

Can anyone help with thoughts?

Comment: hosting css/js/images on your local server is 100% better than calling external files...

Answer (score 4):

Try Speed up plugins

1. W3 Total Cache
2. wp -rocket
3. WP Smush

Answer (score 2):

There's a [good article](https://wpthemeset.com/tips-tricks/how-to-speed-up-wordpress-website/) that I found recently that outlines a few key areas that can be improved in a WordPress website, but long story short:

1. Add more resources/upgrade your current hosting plan
2. Limit the amount of resources that have to be loaded in
3. Minify CSS and JS assets
4. Disable/Remove unused plugins
5. Install a caching plugin - [W3 Total cache](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) is a safe bet.
6. Optimise images - [WP.SMUSH Pro](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wp-smush-pro/) or [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://ewww.io/)
7. Use a CDN to serve static assets - [MAXCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/setup-wordpress-with-w3-total-cache/) or [Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/227634427-Using-Cloudflare-with-WordPress) tend to be among the top choices.